# Stuck with while loop. In processing

Tags: java, processing

I have an array of 100 numbers and I only gave the array even values.  How can I print out how many elements of the array I have to add to obtain a sum < than 1768 using a WHILE LOOP? The following is what I have so far and I am stuck... thanks in advance for the help

```
void setup() {

  int[] x = new int[100];
  int i=0;
  int sum=0;

  for(i=0; i<100; i++) {
    if (i%2==0) {
      x[i]=i;
      sum+=x[i];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `how many elements` -> You need to say more.. Minimum no or maximum no? Or it doesn't matter?

Comment: sorry! i need the max number of elements before the sum of even numbers which is what i assigned to the array is 1768!

Comment: If one of your requirements say to use a while loop, why does your current progress utilize a for loop?

Comment: do you need to sum up even elements until you get to 1768?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 void setup() {
     int i = 0;
     int sum = 0;
     int counter = 0;

     while (sum < 1768) {
         sum += i;
         i += 2;
         counter++;
     }

     System.out.println(counter);
 }
```

You start with the even index of 0. Then just skip odd numbers by using `i += 2`.
If the number of elements is limited with 100, add `i < 200` to the `while` condition:

```
while (sum < 1768 && i < 200)
```

<sub>The array of 100 even numbers will contain numbers from 0 to 200.</sub>

The variable `counter` will contain the number of additions performed. Its value will be equal to `i / 2`, so you can remove that additional variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this loop and element number would be `i+1`.

```
       for(int i=0,k=0; k<1768; i++,k+=x[i]) {
        System.out.println(x[i]+" - "+k);
       }
```

While loop -

```
   int i=0,k=0;
   while(k<1768; ) {
        System.out.println(x[i]+" - "+k);
        i++,k+=x[i];
       }
```

Comment: Any way to see this in a while loop?

Comment: @Quoi Based on the strange requirement and the odd restriction, it's probably homework.

Comment: it is a tutorial... Self improvement.

Answer (score 2):

You are skipping indexes in your array.You are only filling every other 'slot'
Also, it would probably be easier to use a while loop to check against your max value (1728)

```
        int[] x = new int[100];
        int i = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int max = 1728;

        while (sum < max && i < 100)
        {
            x[i] = i*2;
            if ((x[i] + sum) < max)
            {
                sum += x[i];
            }
            i++;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void setup() {

  int[] x = new int[100];
  int maxValue = 1768;
  int i;
  int sum=0;

  while(sum<maxValue) {
    if (i%2==0) {
      x[i]=i;
      sum+=x[i];
      i++;
    }
  }

   System.out.println(i+" Elements needed")

}
```

Answer (score -1):

following is code:

```
void setup() {

  int[] x = new int[100];
  int i=0;
  int sum=0;

  for(i=0; i<100; i++) {
    if (i%2==0) {
      sum += i;
            if(sum<1768){

                 num +=1; 
            }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: We need a Java answer for this question.

Comment: that is similar to what I initially had, but it must be completed using a while loop!

Comment: "Must be completed using a while loop" > that's news to us. Is that a requirement?

Comment: yes it is, sorry i forgot to mention that in the question! sorry!